# Flickery on page load or when switch the page

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have this code bellow that I used it to change form the light mode into the dark mode.The code work, but there is some problem when I use dark mode then switch or change into other page or when I load the page there is some flickery. Is there any sugestion for this problem?. I really apreciate it:

```
// Light and dark mode function
const themeTogler = document.querySelector('.theme-togler');
const sunSpan = themeTogler.querySelector('.active');
const moonSpan = themeTogler.querySelector('span:not(.active)');

// Fungsi untuk mengubah tema
function toggleTheme() {
  sunSpan.classList.toggle('active');
  moonSpan.classList.toggle('active');

  // Cek apakah tema saat ini adalah tema terang atau gelap
  const isLightTheme = sunSpan.classList.contains('active');

  // Mengubah nilai warna sesuai dengan tema yang aktif
  if (isLightTheme) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-white', 'hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-white-variant', 'hsla(216, 44%, 95%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-info-light', 'hsl(216, 44%, 88%)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark', 'hsla(216, 22%, 30%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark-variant', 'hsla(216, 22%, 45%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-info-dark', 'hsla(216, 22%, 65%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-primary-link', 'hsla(217, 60%, 50%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--swiper-theme-color', 'hsla(211, 100%, 50%, 1)');

    // Simpan tema terang ke local storage
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-white', 'hsla(216, 22%, 30%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-white-variant', 'hsla(216, 22%, 45%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-info-light', 'hsla(216, 22%, 65%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark', 'hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark-variant', 'hsla(216, 44%, 95%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-info-dark', 'hsl(216, 44%, 88%)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-primary-link', 'hsla(217, 60%, 80%, 1)');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--swiper-theme-color', 'hsla(216, 44%, 95%, 1)');

    // Simpan tema gelap ke local storage
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
  }
}

// Tambahkan event listener untuk menjalankan fungsi toggleTheme saat elemen moonSpan diklik
moonSpan.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme);
sunSpan.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme);

// Cek apakah tema sudah disimpan di local storage
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

// Jika tema sudah disimpan, ubah tema sesuai dengan tema yang disimpan di local storage
if (theme === 'dark') {
  moonSpan.click();
}


/* -------------- ROOT VARIABLES -------------- */
:root {
  /* ROOT COLOR */
  --color-primary: hsla(217, 60%, 50%, 1);
  --color-primary-hover: hsl(217, 60%, 80%);
  --color-red: hsla(348, 85%, 45%, 1);
  --color-red-hover: hsla(348, 85%, 75%, 1);
  --color-green: hsla(157, 85%, 40%, 1);
  --color-green-hover: hsla(157, 85%, 75%, 1);
  --color-warning: hsla(45, 85%, 55%, 1);
  --color-warning-hover: hsla(45, 85%, 88%, 1);
  --color-purple: hsla(255, 55%, 75%);

  /* Warna Light dan Dark Mode */
  --color-primary-link: hsla(217, 60%, 50%, 1);
  --color-white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  --color-white-variant: hsla(216, 44%, 95%, 1);
  --color-info-light: hsl(216, 44%, 88%);
  --color-dark: hsla(216, 22%, 30%, 1);
  --color-dark-variant: hsla(216, 22%, 45%, 1);
  --color-info-dark: hsla(216, 22%, 65%, 1);
  /* Warna Swiper Btn */
  --swiper-theme-color: hsl(211, 100%, 50%);
  
  /* ROOT Border Radius */
  --card-border-radius: 2rem;
  --modal-border-radius:1rem;
  --border-radius-1: 0.4rem;
  --border-radius-2: 0.8rem;
  --circle-border-radius: 50%;


  --card-padding: 1.8rem;

  --transition: all 300ms ease;

  --box-shadow: 0 2rem 3rem var(--color-info-light);
}
```

When it is in a dark mode then I load or when I jump into other page it should not flicker and stay at dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

The way the browsers work is that if there is a  tag in your head or at the very beginning of your body, this script will block the rendering of the page until it hasn't completed.

In general you want to avoid this, as you add unnecessary burden on the rendering of the page, and it will delay everything else.
But for critical rendering like this one, this is okay.

All you have to do is add something like the following in your HTML:

```
<body>
  <script>
    const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
    document.body.className = theme;
  </script>

  <!-- rest of your html -->
</body>
```